# SQL How to check whether all values inside a column are the same?

Tags: sql

So let's say that for a specific ID (that is not unique) I have these values:

```
ID      | Value
id11111 | Value1
id11111 | Value1
id11111 | Value2
id11111 | Value1
id22222 | Value3
id22222 | Value3
id22222 | Value3
```

My objective would be to return "id11111" since there is a row where the value is different from the others (value2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(value) <> max(value);
```

Comment: Damn that was so simple!! Thank you, will accept when I can. Also added "when value is not null" to it so it ignores nulls.